# Issue in using IMU MPU 6050

Tags: ros, ekf, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have been trying to implement MPU 6050 imu sensor using, [MPU SERIAL NODE](https://github.com/fsteinhardt/mpu6050_serial_to_imu) , when i initially run the node, IMU values seem fine, for example, linear accelerations in x, y, z directions come to be ~0 , ~0 , ~ 9.8. orientation values of x,y,z,w seem to be fine as well, w ~ 1 rest ~ 0, However the moment i run my robot using teleop_twist, The values of these variables jump rapidly, i have attached a rosbag file to see how abrupt the jump occurs. also at the same time a warn message in console appears which is
WARN : TF to MSG quaternions not properly normalized !
due to this i am not able to use the robot localization package cause my wheel odometery is not good, i.e laser scans drift over time and amcl cannot match them with given odom. I hope to resolve this issue by sensor fusion.

can any one help to resolve this issue ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412318/issue-in-using-imu-mpu-6050/) by [Rahulwashere](https://answers.ros.org/users/56480/rahulwashere/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2023-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this issue by turning off the Publish tf from odom to baselink in my controller node, since i am using arduino to directly publish velocity values instead of using differential drive controller. I have my own controller.cpp node to do it.
anyway the values don't jump around any more.

---

Originally posted by [Rahulwashere](https://answers.ros.org/users/56480/rahulwashere/) with karma: 23 on 2023-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0